# Minimum chars of TextInput in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to do custom TimePicker like 00:00. To make it look like this I need to set minimum amount of chars in TextInput.
Now if it's midnight I get 0:0 which is inappropriate.

Is there any way to make it look good?

Comment: Why don't you use `QTime` which can be easily converted to `QString` in the format you prefer?: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtime.html#toString

Comment: @Moe Abdul-Hameed I need to have editable text field with formatted string in it. Can you make an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're looking for something like this:

```
TextInput {
    inputMask: "00:00:00"
    cursorVisible: true
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhTime
    text: "00:00:00"
}
```